# Cloth sim not working in asset

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a scene with a cloth awning.  See the pic below.  I baked this sim and then applied the modifier, deleted all the physics.  So now I have this static canopy mesh in the scene.  Exactly what I want.
[image]

So I've marked the whole scene as an asset in my asset library, and when I import the asset into a bigger scene the canopy comes in as a flat plane, not the mesh at all.  Any ideas what's going on?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying the Cloth simulation, Convert the object to Mesh
Select the object, go to Object > Convert > Mesh

[image]